# Retrieving icons from assets via MdIconRegistry and DomSanitizer

Tags: angular, angular-material

Hi I have a `components/home-component/home.component.html` and `components/home-component/home.component.ts` in my project. I also have a `svg` file `assets/homenav/home_icon.svg`. I am loading the icons in the constructor of the `home.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MdIconRegistry } from '@angular/material';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private iconRegistry: MdIconRegistry, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
        iconRegistry.addSvgIcon('home', sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('assets/homenav/home_icon.svg'));        
    }

    ngOnInit() { }

}
```

If I run my app the app itself works fine. Though the icon is not being rendered. I am loading the icon like this:

```
<md-icon class="homeNavIcon" color="primary" svgIcon="home"></md-icon>
```

There are **no error messages** or any other complaining. If I enter `http://localhost:4200/assets/homenav/home_icon.svg` as url the icon gets displayed in the browser correctly.

Also if I set a breakpoint the `HomeComponent` constructor and try to call `iconRegistry`call in the console I get:

[image]

I also tried changing the url to:

```
iconRegistry.addSvgIcon('home', sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('/../../../assets/homenav/home_icon.svg'));
```

and several other combinations with no luck. It also **seems to work** if I place the `home.component` **directly into the `app` folder**.

Am I providing the wrong url or am I missing something else here.

**Update:**

I realized that `svgElement` is also null if the icon are displayed correctly in my other projects. I also I wanted to provide an overview over my `@NgModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    MdCardModule,
    HttpModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthGuard,
    AuthenticationService,
    UserService,
    // providers used to create fake backend
    fakeBackendProvider,
    MockBackend,
    BaseRequestOptions
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Update 2:**

As I already supposed the icons from the `MdIconRegistry` are never even loaded. I can insert any nonsense as Url this will not throw any errors. i.e.:

```
iconRegistry.addSvgIcon('home', 
sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('LoremIpsumblabla'));
```

This call will not throw any exceptions, while in another project I get:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) :4200/LoremIpsumblabla

Comment: Is HomeComponent part of your main AppModule, or a sub-module?

Comment: @Z.Bagley a sub module

Comment: Did you make sure to include MdCardModule in the submodule as well as the app module?

Comment: @Z.Bagley import { MaterialModule, MdCardModule } from '@angular/material';

Comment: And you have it in the `@NgModule({ imports: [ ..., MdCardModule], ... })`?

Comment: Yes I do, will edit question.

Comment: Could you update with the Sub-Module info as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the path to this

```
'./assets/homenav/home_icon.svg'
```

Comment: Well its pretty difficult to diagnose any further without seeing the code for "addSvgIcon", or at least having more context'

Comment: addSvgIcon comes with MdIconRegistry from angular-material

Comment: Hmm, I've looked at the code and it doesn't really help me  :-p .. all it does is add the icon to a map of svg icon configurations. You appear to be calling it correctly judging from the code and documentation. And if its not giving an error the path should be ok. Hard to say